# Compact ball in a closed subspace of X

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, compactness, holder-spaces

Consider the $B$-space $X = C([0, 1])$ equipped with the norm $\Vert · \Vert_{\infty}$. And let $F$ be a closed subspace of $X$ such that every function $u\in F$ is Holder continuous, namely, for each $u \in F$ there exist $\alpha \in (0, 1]$ and $L\gt0$ such that $ |u(t) − u(s)| \le L|t − s|^{\alpha} \ \ \forall t,s \in [0,1] $.

$(i)$ Setting, for every $n\in  \mathbb{N}_{0}$
\begin{align} F_{n} = \{ u \in F : |u(t) − u(s)| \le n|t − s|^{1/n}, \ \  \forall t, s \in [0, 1] \} \end{align}
and using the Baire theorem prove that there exist $ \beta \in (0, 1]$ and $M\gt0 \ $  (both independent of $u$) such that, for all $ u\in F$ \begin{align}
  |u(t) − u(s)| \le M \Vert u \Vert_{\infty}|t − s|^{\beta}, \ \ \forall t, s \in [0, 1] \end{align}

$(ii)$ Prove that the closed unit ball $B_{F} \subset F$ centered at $0$ is compact and deduce that F is ﬁnite-dimensional.

If I have a compact ball in $F$, doesn't it contradict the fact that in a infinite-dim space ($X$ in this case) balls are never compact?

Answer (score 1):

No.  $\alpha$-Hölder is not preserved by $\lVert-\rVert_\infty$, so $F$ is not a closed subspace of $(C([0,1]), \lVert-\rVert_\infty)$ (e.g., $F$ contains all polynomials, so its closure in sup norm is $C([0,1])$ by Stone-Weierstrass).  See also [this question from a few hours ago](/questions/3274908).

Comment: so $B_{F}$ is not with $\Vert ⋅\Vert _{\infty}$ ?

Comment: What is $B_F$ supposed to mean?

Comment: Ah sorry, the closed unit ball in $F$

Comment: "the closed unit ball in $F$" doesn't make any sense, without you first specifying a norm on $F$.  Are you putting the **incomplete** sup-norm on $F$?

Comment: It is not specified. To have a $F$ ﬁnite-dimensional closed subspace of $X$ should I use the Holder norm?

Comment: No, $F$ is never going to be finite-dimensional, since it has to contain all polynomials.

Comment: I edited the question with the original problem. Maybe here F doesn't contain all the Holder continuous functions?